# When I execute 'npm install experss ' no node modules/package-lock.json is shown

Tags: express, npm

Also I noted that execution is successful with no errors

I tried various tries like --save,-D etc but none of them work.

I think they are installed globally, if this is true can you plz tell how to localize the npm install

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show exactly what command you're running and what you're doing to verify that it did not behave as expected

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your project is a node project. Your command has a typo error , try to run `npm install express` inside your folder. For more help try to share the structure of your project.